# How do I get my Android TODOs to show up in Tasks in Eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-indigo, todo, tasklist

I have // TODO
throughout my .java files and they are detected and labeled as tasks
[image: Properly Detected]

but they are not listed in the Tasks list.
[image: But not listed]
How can I make them show up in the Tasks list?  It would make it so much easier to jump from task to task if they were in the Tasks list.

Comment: Turned out all I needed to do was open the tasks view from Window => Show View => Tasks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to `Windows -> Preferences` in Eclipse, then navigate to `Java -> Compiler -> Task Tags`.  Verify that the `TODO` is listed as a tag that indicates a task in Java comments.

If that is configured correctly, then in the Tasks view open the drop down and select `Configure contents...` to confirm that Java tasks are listed as one of the things to show in the Tasks view.

Comment: Did that, still does not work.  However, when I open an old Android project, it's TODOs do show up in the list.

Comment: Ok, I figured it out.  You have to build the project or compile the file before the tasks will show up in the tasks list.  I don't like that.

Comment: Build or Compile to add to list since Task Tags is attached to the Compiler portion of the Java Perspective rather than the Editor portion.

Answer (score 1):

I only need to save the project (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>) and the task shows up :) I think the tasks are someway bound to the save function. Because when you Compile or Build it does a save first :)